# MSBuild subtlety with item metadata?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

Consider an item type `FooItem` in an MSBuild project.

In a task we can make references to items and their metadata such as:

```
%(FooItem.BarMetadata)
```

or

```
@(FooItem->'Metadata("BarMetadata")')
```

or

```
@(FooItem->'%(BarMetadata)')
```

Is there any difference between these three approaches, which seem identical to me? Obviously the transform syntax (`->`) is more powerful in general, but I've explicitly given a simple example equivalent to the use of the `%` operator, from what I can tell.

Furthermore, is there any effect on task batching here (presuming these expressions are within a task item)? In general, I'm wondering if there's any way to prevent task batching by metadata while still referring to some metadata in a task.

Answer (score 3):

There are *not* identical. The transform syntax appends the input to a semicolon-delimited [`Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx) array. The `%` notation adds the input to an [`ItemGroup Element`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/646dk05y.aspx).

Consider the following target:

```
<Target Name="TestMetadata">

  <ItemGroup>
    <Files Include="File1.doc">
      <Description>Word Document</Description>
    </Files>
    <Files Include="File2.xls">
      <Description>Excel Document</Description>
    </Files>
    <Files Include="File3.pps">
      <Description>PowerPoint Presentation</Description>
    </Files>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Message Text="Transform: @(Files->'%(FullPath) is %(Description)')" />
  <Message Text="Direct: %(Files.FullPath) is %(Files.Description)" />

</Target>
```

As the output shows, those notations produce different output:

```
TestMetadata:   
 Transform: C:\MSBuild\File1.doc is Word Document;C:\MSBuild\File2.xls is Excel Document;C:\\MSBuild\File3.pps is PowerPoint Presentation
Direct: C:\MSBuild\File1.doc is Word Document   
Direct: C:\MSBuild\File2.xls is Excel Document   
Direct: C:\MSBuild\File3.pps is PowerPoint Presentation
```

Comment: So basically what you're saying is that the transform syntax (`->`) doesn't do any task batching, whereas `%` does... Seems all, right?

Comment: No. You can use both for batching as there's very little between them. I'd use `->` when I need simple non-formatted array of strings.

Comment: But clearly it *is* batching in the first case, and not the second. Explain that.

Comment: [here](http://www.thefriendlycoder.com/2011/11/23/msbuild-gotchas-task-batching/)

Comment: Well that's neither here nor there really. It seems that indeed the only difference between those two examples I gave *is* batching due to the presence of the `%` operator.

Comment: The transform syntax (->) in either form avoids batching. It transforms every item in the list into a "temporary, nameless list" which then behaves like any other list -- as if you'd used @(foo) directly.  The bare metadata syntax (no ->) causes batching; it takes one item at a time.  Dan (msbuild)

Comment: @cheerlessbog: Thanks, that's good info. In fact if you quoted the source and put in an answer of its own, I might even accept it!